# Invoking function with different objects race condition

Tags: c++, multithreading, race-condition

i am wondering if the following example leads to a race condition.

I have two threads and both calling a function at the same time which takes an reference to an object as argument and does something with it.
Both threads invoke these function with different objects.

Example code

```
void foo(object& obj) {
    // read/write to object

}

// thread1
object obj1;
foo(obj1);

// thread2
object obj2;
foo(obj2);
```

My thoughts are that every thread has its own stack. So invoking foo() will create variables etc. on threads own stack so no memory will be shared. It only would be an race condition if the argument object to foo is shared memory.
Am i right or do i forget something?!

Comment: Assuming `foo()` is sane (for the purpose of this question: doesn't access any other objects than its argument), and `object` is sane (doesn't contain any pointers/references to objects not contained in the object itself) then the *only* way for this to have a race condition would be to pass the *same* `object` to `foo()` in multiple threads. Whether the objects are in "shared memory" (whatever you believe that to be) doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no race condition unless the thread modifies other thread `objx`.

If the thread can read only other thread objx you need to make sure that modifications and reads are atomic.